# Vertical placement of content in beamer slides

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I don't get how to achieve my desired vertical placement with `beamer`. Let me give you my MWE first:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node[anchor=north west,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\insertframetitle};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{This is the title}
Test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
%\frametitle{This slide has no title}
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I want to achieve with the frame title is to place it directly at the top of the slide, but I get a small white skip before my box, so the box is not placed, where I would expect it:
[image]

The second thing I want to achieve is, that the main content of every content slide is placed in the same box, or the same location, so to speak, no matter if there is a title or not. But as far as I see, if there is no `\frametitle`, beamer does not make use of the `frametitle` template and so I don't see a way to achieve this behavior.

Thanks for any suggestions, comments, improvement, or solution proposals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things are going on here. To remove all white space between the boxes, this would be the appropriate settings:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \node[anchor=north west,fill=red,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {\insertframetitle};%
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \vspace*{-0.25ex}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{This is the title}
    \nointerlineskip
    Test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\nointerlineskip
Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So basically `\vspace{0.25ex}` are always introduced through beamer between frame title and content, which we have to get rid of. And the `\nointerlineskip` is also suppressed between all sorts of vboxes. Then we get minimum spacing.